# Python: matplotlib 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'has_data'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I wanted to get a 3D plot with matplotlib module. Below is some of my source code.

```
(LTV,DTI,FICO) = readData('Acquisition_2007Q1.txt')
x = np.array(LTV)
y = np.array(DTI)
z = np.array(FICO)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
Axes3D.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap = cm.jet)
```

The `x`, `y`, and `z` are like:

```
array([56, 56, 56, ..., 62, 62, 62])
array([37, 37, 37, ..., 42, 42, 42])
array([734, 734, 734, ..., 709, 709, 709])
```

However, I got the error below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5c9578cf3311> in <module>()
      1 fig = plt.figure()
      2 ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
----> 3 Axes3D.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap = cm.jet)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py in plot_trisurf(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1828         """
   1829 
-> 1830         had_data = self.has_data()
   1831 
   1832         # TODO: Support custom face colours

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'has_data'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be

```
(LTV,DTI,FICO) = readData('Acquisition_2007Q1.txt')
x = np.array(LTV)
y = np.array(DTI)
z = np.array(FICO)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap = cm.jet)
```

The `Axes3D.plot_trisurf` line is calling the un-bound class method `plot_trisurf` of the `Axes3D` class.  It expects an instance of `Axes3D` to be the first argument (which is normally taken care of when the method is bound to an instance).

Comment: I had the same problem because the docs for Axes3D don't give any examples.